# Show transition with css in React

Tags: css, reactjs, transition

[image]

I am trying to achieve something similar to above  but my code is in React

```
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ClassNames from 'classnames/bind';
import SlidePanel from 'yoda-site-components/lib/components/SlidePanel/SlidePanel';
import TokenProvider from 'yoda-site-components/lib/helpers/TokenProvider/TokenProvider';

// wrappers
import LoginWrapper from './wrappers/LoginWrapper';
import CreateAccountWrapper from './wrappers/CreateAccountWrapper';
import PasswordResetWrapper from './wrappers/PasswordResetWrapper';
import Welcome from './wrappers/Welcome';
import * as styles from './SignInSlider.css';

const cx = ClassNames.bind(styles);

class SignInSlider extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        isOpenPanel: PropTypes.bool,
        onClosePanel: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        signInDetails: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
        createAccount: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
        preferences: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
        messagesTexts: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
        deviceType: PropTypes.shape({
            isMobile: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
            isDesktop: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        }).isRequired,
        signInActions: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.func).isRequired,
        createAccountActions: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.func).isRequired,
        passwordResetActions: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.func).isRequired,
        passwordResetDetails: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object),
        signInSliderActions: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.func).isRequired,
        showCreateAccountPage: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        showWelcomePage: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        showForgotPasswordPage: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    };
    static defaultProps = {
        isOpenPanel: false,
        passwordResetDetails: {
            passwordResetResponse: {},
        },
    };
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onClickOfCreateAccountButton = this.onClickOfCreateAccountButton.bind(this);
        this.onClickPasswordReset = this.onClickPasswordReset.bind(this);
        this.onClosePanel = this.onClosePanel.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log(nextProps);
        if (nextProps.showWelcomePage) {
            this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                //this.onClosePanel();
            }, 3000);
        }
    }

    onClickOfCreateAccountButton() {
    const el = document.getElementsByClassName('SignInSlider-loginSlider')[0];
    const el1 = document.getElementsByClassName('SignInSlider-createAccountSlider')[0];

    el.classList.add('animate-show');
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.signInSliderActions.openCreateAccountPage();
        el1.classList.add('animate-show');
    }, 800);
}

    onClickPasswordReset() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.signInSliderActions.openForgotPasswordResetPage();
        }, 800);
    }

    onClosePanel() {
        this.timer && clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.props.signInSliderActions.resetSignInSlider();
        this.props.onClosePanel();
    }

    render() {
        const { deviceType, preferences, messagesTexts, signInDetails, createAccount } = this.props;
        const { showCreateAccountPage, showWelcomePage, showForgotPasswordPage } = this.props;
        return (
            <SlidePanel
                isOpenPanel={this.props.isOpenPanel}
                onClosePanel={this.onClosePanel}>

                <div className={cx('signInSliderPanel')}>

                    <div className={cx('loginSlider')}>
                        { !showCreateAccountPage && !showWelcomePage && !showForgotPasswordPage &&
                        <LoginWrapper
                            signInDetails={signInDetails}
                            deviceType={deviceType}
                            preferences={preferences}
                            messagesTexts={messagesTexts}
                            source="account"
                            actions={this.props.signInActions}
                            onClickOfCreateAccountButton={this.onClickOfCreateAccountButton}
                            onClickPasswordReset={this.onClickPasswordReset}
                            isSignInSliderReq
                    />
                } </div>

                    <div className={cx('createAccountSlider')}>
                        {showCreateAccountPage &&
                        <CreateAccountWrapper
                            createAccount={createAccount}
                            isSignInSliderReq
                            deviceType={deviceType}
                            messagesTexts={this.props.messagesTexts}
                            preferences={this.props.preferences}
                            actions={this.props.createAccountActions}/>} </div>
                    <div className={cx('passwordSlider')}>
                        {showForgotPasswordPage &&
                        <PasswordResetWrapper
                            isSignInSliderReq
                            messagesTexts={messagesTexts.passwordReset}
                            preferences={preferences}
                            createAccountActions={this.props.createAccountActions}
                            actions={this.props.passwordResetActions}
                            passwordResetDetails={this.props.passwordResetDetails}
                            deviceType
               />} </div>
                    <div className={cx('welcomeSlider')}>
                        { showWelcomePage &&
                        <Welcome messagesTexts= {messagesTexts.signInSlider}
                            firstName={TokenProvider.get('DP_USER_NAME')}/>} </div>
                </div>
            </SlidePanel>
        );
    }
}

export default SignInSlider;
```

onClickofcreateaccount I am trying to transition to next page however nothing is happening:

```
    .signInSliderPanel {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 422px;

    & .loginSlider {
        height: 100%;
        width: 422px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    & .createAccountSlider {
        height: 100%;
        width: 422px;
    }
}

.animate-show {
    height: 100%;
    width: 422px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(-422px, 0, 0);
    transition: all 1.25s linear 0s;
    will-change: transform;
}
```

I also made a codepen.io code to mimic what i want.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQdgmV

Comment: maybe this?  `import classNames from 'classnames/bind';`  https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames#alternate-bind-version-for-css-modules-

Comment: @Kunukn That works fine no issue with including CSS

Comment: 1) `import * as styles from './SignInSlider.css'` looks like you are working with css but the source code for your css looks like sass or less. 2) In your `onClickOfCreateAccountButton` method you are working with DOM manipulation. React should handle the DOM updates for you. You should set state values and render classNames from your state in your render method.

Comment: @Kunukn You were right SignInSlider-animate-show component name had to be added to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.

**My animation function:**

```
   onClickOfCreateAccountButton() {
    const el = document.getElementsByClassName('SignInSlider-loginSlider')[0];
    const el1 = document.getElementsByClassName('SignInSlider-createAccountSlider')[0];

    el.classList.add('SignInSlider-animate-show');
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.signInSliderActions.openCreateAccountPage();
        el1.classList.add('SignInSlider-animate-show');
    }, 1000);
}
```

My CSS:

```
.signInSliderPanel {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 422px;

& .loginSlider {
    height: 100%;
    width: 422px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}

& .createAccountSlider {
    height: 100%;
    width: 422px;
    left: 422px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}

& .passwordSlider {
    height: 100%;
    width: 422px;
    left: 422px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}

  & .animate-show {
    height: 100%;
    width: 422px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(-422px, 0, 0);
    transition: all 1.25s linear 0s;
    will-change: transform;
    display: block;
  }
```

}

What I am doing above is adding animate-show to show the transition first and then add it to the incoming page.